# MVC Application_start localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I get error:

> localhost redirected you too many times.

when I redirect to error page from `Application_Start` method.

my code looks like this:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();   

        if (exception != null)
        {    
            Session["w"] = exception;
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Error");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you have an error when you display view /admin/error?

Comment: no... it gives me an empty page says localhost redirected you too many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use Session in that case. If the error is triggered from an `IHttpHandler` not marked with `IRequiresSessionState`, then accessing Session will fail. So, you will have a redirect loop.

Remove using of session and try to use:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Admin/Error?w={0}", exception.Message));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) ... now it gives me this message The controller for path '/favicon.ico' was not found or does not implement IController.

I think i need first to filter the exception type

Comment: Sure, i did :) ... now i have another problem... when it redirects to Error View if the user clicks on refresh it makes the same error again, can you please help me to avoid that

Comment: Thanks @Tom. So, as I said If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. Describe your new problem in the new question and leave the link here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more then likely related to a `File Not Found` error caused by the missing `favicon.ico` file which you've mentioned above.

To resolve, simply add a `favicon.ico` file into the project root.

Optionally, you can update the error handling to avoid redirecting when a 404 is detected.

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();   

    if (exception != null && exception != 404)
    {    
        Session["w"] = exception;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Error");    
    }
}
```